# Facebook sdk login crashes app on Kindle Fire emulator

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, kindle-fire

My app has no functionality without Facebook integration, so the very first thing my app does in onCreate is log into Facebook, providing it with a listener that will grab the user's news feed and then load it into my app. However, on the Kindle Fire emulator, my app can't even open the login dialog for Facebook, using the authorize call from the SDK.

This login as well as the rest of my app runs flawlessly for me on several test devices, and every AVD emulator that I have created except the official Kindle Fire emulator that I installed from the SDK manager. I sadly don't have access to a Kindle Fire, so I can't test it on a real device.

In an effort to isolate the problem, I temporarily modified my code to do absolutely nothing in the callback listener, I just leave an empty void method for my onDataLoaded() implementation. In onCreate, I am calling the following:

```
        m_fbHelper.authorize(new NFDataLoadedListener() {

        public void onDataLoaded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, this);
```

The definition in the FbHelper Class is:

```
public void authorize(NFDataLoadedListener dataLoadedListener, Home homeActivity){
        m_facebook.authorize(homeActivity, s_permissions, new  FacebookDataRetrievalListener(dataLoadedListener));
}
```

When the activity is created and this call is made, a notification box appears that says "loading," which usually happens when logging in. Then the app just crashes and the emulator goes back to the home screen.

The log says this:

> 08-15 01:40:23.338: D/Zygote(32): Process 414 terminated by signal (4)
>
> 08-15 01:40:23.342: I/ActivityManager(61): Process
>   com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro (pid 414) has died.
>
> 08-15 01:40:23.366: E/InputDispatcher(61): channel '405ea458
>
> com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro/com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro.Home
>   (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. 
>   events=0x8
>
> 08-15 01:40:23.366: E/InputDispatcher(61): channel '405ea458
>   com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro/com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro.Home
>   (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   08-15 01:40:23.392: I/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{4061da60
>   com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro/com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro.Home
>   paused=false}
>
> 08-15 01:40:23.422: I/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{405ea458
>   com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro/com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro.Home
>   paused=false}
>
> 08-15 01:40:23.482: I/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{40636a48
>   com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro/com.mattgmg.socialadvancedpro.Home
>   paused=false}
>
> 08-15 01:40:23.512: E/InputDispatcher(61): Received spurious receive
>   callback for unknown input channel.  fd=175, events=0x8
>
> 08-15 01:40:23.512: E/InputDispatcher(61): Received spurious receive
>   callback for unknown input channel.  fd=178, events=0x8
>
> 08-15 01:40:23.863: I/LAB126(119): StatusBarService hears intent.
>   action: com.lab126.intent.TOP_WINDOW_CHANGED

Since there is no stack trace, I can't figure out why the Facebook SDK failed to bring up the login dialog. Other SO posts say that these log messages indicate a memory leak, but I haven't done anything in the app yet besides try to log into Facebook, so it must be an SDK problem if it is a memory leak.